# Export template function

Tags: c++, python, templates, boost, export

I have [templated function](http://clanlib.org/docs/clanlib-2.2/reference_doxygen/classCL__Signal__v2.html) `connect`:

```
template<class InstanceClass>
CL_Slot connect (InstanceClass *instance, void(InstanceClass::*function)(Param1, Param2))
```

It connects for some signal passed function from `InstanceClass`.

In my example, I want to connect some of classes for the keyboard event (KeyDown).
In c++ I write:

```
get_signal_object().connect(&SomeClass::func);
```

But I have to use this function in python-script with exporting from c++ code (using boost.python).

As I know, to export template I have to export it passing any used type. But in python I'll pass classes which exist only in python-namespace.

So, any ideas how to use that function templated in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just add

```
extern template<>
    CL_Slot connect<SomeClass> (SomeClass *instance, void(InstanceClass::*function)(Param1, Param2));
```

**note: extern might need to after `template<>` -- don't remember**

If you must have C linkage add a wrapper function (it will inline the templated function).

---

Note: MSVC has [nonstandard template export facilities](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q168958/)

c++0x has upcoming support for extern templates: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Extern_template

Comment: You didn't understand. Look: I don't know the types I'll pass into that function from C++! So, I don't know how to inline it because I don't have types.

Comment: Perhaps I understood but answered more general than you think is '_correct_'. What you need then, was in the second part of the answer. I'm not sure whether boost.python supports it already

Comment: @Vjo: source? http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1448.pdf, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Extern_template, http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html still list it

Comment: @VJo : `export` was removed; `extern` is a linkage specifier that is completely orthogonal to templates.